# how to purge VirtualBox and reinstall it

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dpkg

Once i was a fool trying to remove Virtualbox from my Ubuntu16.10 yakkety by hands and deleted /usr/lib/virtualbox/ completely. Then i realised that the package i needed to purge is called virtualbox-5.1:i386 and tried

```
$ sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-5.1:i386
```

which is stably giving

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-5.1:i386 (--purge):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.1.postinst: 95: /var/lib/dpkg/info                 
/virtualbox-5.1.postinst: /usr/lib/virtualbox/prerm-common.sh: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.1.postinst: 96: /var/lib/dpkg/info  
/virtualbox-5.1.postinst: /usr/lib/virtualbox/postinst-common.sh: not found
Errors were encountered while processing:
virtualbox-5.1:i386
```

I can neither restore the existed version nor write the new one. Please could you give any advice.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt remove --purge virtualbox-5.1`?

Comment: run `dpkg -L virtualbox-5.1` to see the files that are associated with it, then plan to remove them

Comment: Yes, apt remove --purge ... starts doing sth, then shows dos-like dialogue that there're vms operating (????), pressing ok aborts the process givinf the terminal i posted.

Comment: dpkg -L gives no associated files